# How do I get this cookie banner to work?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have implemented a cookie consent script by Creare: https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/js/js-eu-cookie-law-banner

in my website: http://www.azltd.co.uk/

but I cannot get it to work.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your cookie-consent.js file.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if(checkCookie(window.cookieName) != window.cookieValue){
        createDiv(); 
    }
}
```

Doesn't have a closing bracket. It should be

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if(checkCookie(window.cookieName) != window.cookieValue){
        createDiv(); 
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Adam thats great - however I have the same problem on this site: https://www.drive-tastic.co.uk/
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @user3067865 I opened that site and didn't have any issues. Could you be more specific with the issue? also if this solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh I think it was a caching problem - just opened it on another computer and it works fine - great thanks again

Comment: @user3067865 Glad I could help.